# Removing right edge from pyplot histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I refer to this [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_cumulative.html) from the Matplotlib site. To the right of the blue "Empirical" curve, there is a vertical blue line, which is the right edge of the rightmost bar.

How can I remove this vertical blue line, without changing the x-axis limits?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is default behavior. You need to delete the last point.

```
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, n_bins, normed=1, histtype='step',
                           cumulative=True, label='Empirical')

patches[0].set_xy(patches[0].get_xy()[:-1])
```

The rest are the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The vertical line is an artifact of how the plot is produced.  You are making a bar chart, but only plotting the corners; but the last corner is always at 0.  You can bypass this issue by generating the histogram data yourself using numpy (which is what pyplot uses anyway), and making a step graph of the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

mu = 200
sigma = 25
n_bins = 50
x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, size=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

# get the counts and edges of the histogram data
cnt, edges = np.histogram(x, bins=n_bins, normed=1)
# plot the data as a step plot.  note that edges has an extra right edge.
ax.step(edges[:-1], cnt.cumsum())

plt.show()
```

[image]